# Get All Columns Names in the selected table provided the class names are passed as a String using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to get the name of all the columns in the selected database provided the condition that the name of the tables whose column to be fetched are in the string array and can be changed on fly.

I have a code where I can get the name of all column of a particular table only:

```
 var properties = from p in typeof(EntityAttribute).GetProperties()
                                                    where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                                           where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute
                                                           select true).FirstOrDefault()
                                                    select new 
                                                    {
                                                        FieldName = p.Name,
                                                        FieldType = p.PropertyType,
                                                        FieldPK = p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() > 0
                                                    };
```

**EntityAttribute** is the name of the column.

The problem is that this class name **EntityAttribute** is a class. i want to pass this class name from the string array.

Example: I have a string array that have the name of say three tables:

Now i want to iterate the code given above by passing the **Class Name** that is in a string

How should I pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetType`

```
Type type = Type.GetType("YourApplication.Namespace.EntityAttribute");
```

Comment: did you use the fully qualified string? `YourApplication.Namespace.EntityAttribute` for example - Updated my answer

Comment: Thnaks i got the fault. Thanks a lot

Comment: great stuff. glad i could help!